# Fetch the unique rows from the tabs using sheets/excel formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I need to build an index table dynamically from the sheetnames of the tabs (BLUE color).

The expected result is shown in YELLOW color.

The rows must be unique along with the sheetnames being displayed in the first column.

[I tried in this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m6jiCb60J9KyxhcP3eitpn6xAsB2o28uVkuTpXItzdc/edit?usp=sharing)

Non Formula formula is here: `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("{",TEXTJOIN(";",true,ARRAYFORMULA("'" &A6:A32 &"'!" & "A2:B")),"}"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A formula solution is not possible for multiple sheets + `indirect`.

One option to solve this is to build the dynamic part of your formula with another formula.

Here's what I mean:
[image]

The dynamic part of the formula is constructed with this formula:

```
={"Dynamic part of the formula" ; JOIN(";"&char(10),FILTER("QUERY({"&A2:A&"!A2:C},""select '"&A2:A&"', Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' label '"&A2:A&"' ''"")",A2:A<>"")) }
```

It assumes column A is released for sheet names only. It produces the result like this:

```
Dynamic part of the formula
QUERY({Sheet1!A2:C},"select 'Sheet1', Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' label 'Sheet1' ''");
QUERY({Sheet2!A2:C},"select 'Sheet2', Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' label 'Sheet2' ''");
QUERY({Sheet3!A2:C},"select 'Sheet3', Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' label 'Sheet3' ''");
QUERY({Sheet4!A2:C},"select 'Sheet4', Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' label 'Sheet4' ''")
```

The final formula uses this part. You'll need to do the next step manually or write a short script for this. Manual process:

Go to a cell with the generated part of the formula. Hit [F2] to enter it, select and copy all. Go to the final formula and replace this part:

```
={"Sheetname","sub_category","category_filter"; QUERY(UNIQUE({

QUERY({Sheet1!A2:C},"select 'Sheet1', Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' label 'Sheet1' ''");
QUERY({Sheet2!A2:C},"select 'Sheet2', Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' label 'Sheet2' ''");
QUERY({Sheet3!A2:C},"select 'Sheet3', Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' label 'Sheet3' ''");
QUERY({Sheet4!A2:C},"select 'Sheet4', Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 != '' label 'Sheet4' ''")

}),"select Col1, Col2, Col3") }
```

Comment: Great solution Max! I really tried to achieve the same but I couldn't :) I vote up for this.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure there must be a more elegant formula to achieve the desired output.

However, this works just fine:

```
=query(UNIQUE({"Sheetname","sub_category","category_filter","duplicate";{ARRAYFORMULA("Sheet1"&T(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A))));ARRAYFORMULA("Sheet2"&T(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet2!A2:A))));
ARRAYFORMULA("Sheet3"&T(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet3!A2:A))))},{INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2:C"&COUNTA(Sheet1!A1:A));
INDIRECT("Sheet2!A2:C"&COUNTA(Sheet2!A1:A));INDIRECT("Sheet3!A2:C"&COUNTA(Sheet3!A1:A))}}),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marios really appreciate. But this is an overhead because I am expecting the formula to be dynamic, if I add new blue cells then the result table must be auto updated. This needs manual changes to formula. How will I make it dynamic?